# Mysql subquery return error when more than one record is fetched from db

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following code to generate a merit list of students' performance in different subjects to display all the students according to their performances.

```
 $qry = "select * from (
 select (select percentage from exams_db where subjecttype = 'English') as English,
           (select percentage from exams_db where subjecttype = 'Biology') as Biology,
           (select percentage from exams_db where subjecttype = 'Maths') as Maths,
           (select percentage from exams_db where subjecttype = 'Science') as Science,
           (select percentage from exams_db where subjecttype = 'SocialStudies') as SocialStudies,
           (select total_marks from exams_db ORDER BY total_marks DESC LIMIT 1) as total_marks,
           (select exam_date from exams_db ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) as exam_date

    from exams_db group by Maths
    union all
    select (select grade from exams_db where subjecttype = 'English') as English,
           (select grade from exams_db where subjecttype = 'Biology' ) as Biology,
           (select grade from exams_db where subjecttype = 'Maths') as Maths,
           (select grade from exams_db where subjecttype = 'Science') as Science,
           (select grade from exams_db where subjecttype = 'SocialStudies') as SocialStudies, 
           (select total_marks from exams_db  ORDER BY total_marks DESC LIMIT 1) as total_marks,
           (select exam_date from exams_db ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) as exam_date

    from exams_db group by Maths
     ) t ";
```

However, i get an error that Subquery returns more than 1 row

However, when i edit the code as below, it works for only one user.

```
$qry = "select * from (
 select (select percentage from exams_db  where subjecttype = 'English' AND user = '$userid') as English,
           (select percentage from exams_db  where subjecttype = 'Biology' AND user = '$userid') as Biology,
           (select percentage from exams_db  where subjecttype = 'Maths' AND user = '$userid') as Maths,
           (select percentage from exams_db  where subjecttype = 'Science' AND user = '$userid') as Science,
           (select percentage from exams_db  where subjecttype = 'SocialStudies' AND user = '$userid') as SocialStudies,
           (select total_marks from exams_db  WHERE user = '$userid' ORDER BY total_marks DESC LIMIT 1) as total_marks,
           (select exam_date from exams_db  WHERE user = '$userid' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) as exam_date

    from exams_db  group by Maths
    union all
    select (select grade from exams_db  where subjecttype = 'English' AND user = '$userid') as English,
           (select grade from exams_db  where subjecttype = 'Biology' AND user = '$userid') as Biology,
           (select grade from exams_db  where subjecttype = 'Maths' AND user = '$userid') as Maths,
           (select grade from exams_db  where subjecttype = 'Science' AND user = '$userid') as Science,
           (select grade from exams_db  where subjecttype = 'SocialStudies' AND user = '$userid') as SocialStudies, 
           (select total_marks from exams_db WHERE user = '$userid' ORDER BY total_marks DESC LIMIT 1) as total_marks,
           (select exam_date from exams_db  WHERE user = '$userid' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) as exam_date

    from exams_db  group by Maths
     ) t ";
```

But, i want to display all users. So, how can i edit my first code to enable me display all users because as much as the second code is helping me, it is allowing me to display only one user.

My database structure is as follows

```
user    subjecttype  percentage  grade

 109283  English       40%         B

 345245  Biology       80%         A

 832904  Science       50%         C
```

Comment: You can join the table itself again and again, but I see this pretty useless, since you are using it in PHP. You don't care how the DB extracts the results. You do smth like `SELECT percentage, subjective, total_marks, exam_date, user FROM exams_db` So you will have on every row the percentage, total marks and the date for subjective, for user

Comment: I am no expert but as far as I can see the subquery produces a virtual table which should contain one entry per row.  It looks like you are returning multiple rows within subquery( subquery.  I am still looking at this my end but I hope this is of some help.

Comment: @RoyalBg fetching that way is not possible because i have designed my table in a different way.See the edit in the question of how my table looks like. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to output here.

However assuming you want a list of all the users and their percentages, and all the users with all their grades, along with the last exam date and highest total marks for that user:-

```
SELECT exam_date.user, English.percentage, Biology.percentage, Maths.percentage, Science.percentage, SocialStudies.percentage, exam_date.ExamDate, total_marks.TotalMarks
FROM (select user, MAX(exam_date) AS ExamDate from exams_db  WHERE user = '$userid' GROUP BY user) as exam_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select user, percentage from exams_db  where subjecttype = 'English' GROUP BY user) as English ON exam_date.user = English.user
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select user, percentage from exams_db  where subjecttype = 'Biology' GROUP BY user) as Biology ON exam_date.user = Biology.user
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select user, percentage from exams_db  where subjecttype = 'Maths' GROUP BY user) as Maths ON exam_date.user = Maths.user
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select user, percentage from exams_db  where subjecttype = 'Science' GROUP BY user) as Science ON exam_date.user = Science.user
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select user, percentage from exams_db  where subjecttype = 'SocialStudies' GROUP BY user) as SocialStudies ON exam_date.user = SocialStudies.user
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select user, MAX(total_marks) AS TotalMarks from exams_db  WHERE user = '$userid' GROUP BY user) as total_marks ON exam_date.user = total_marks.user
UNION ALL
SELECT exam_date.user, English.percentage, Biology.percentage, Maths.percentage, Science.percentage, SocialStudies.percentage, exam_date.ExamDate, total_marks.TotalMarks
FROM (select user, MAX(exam_date) AS ExamDate from exams_db  WHERE user = '$userid' GROUP BY user) as exam_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select user, grade from exams_db  where subjecttype = 'English' GROUP BY user) as English ON exam_date.user = English.user
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select user, grade from exams_db  where subjecttype = 'Biology' GROUP BY user) as Biology ON exam_date.user = Biology.user
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select user, grade from exams_db  where subjecttype = 'Maths' GROUP BY user) as Maths ON exam_date.user = Maths.user
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select user, grade from exams_db  where subjecttype = 'Science' GROUP BY user) as Science ON exam_date.user = Science.user
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select user, grade from exams_db  where subjecttype = 'SocialStudies' GROUP BY user) as SocialStudies ON exam_date.user = SocialStudies.user
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select user, MAX(total_marks) AS TotalMarks from exams_db  WHERE user = '$userid' GROUP BY user) as total_marks ON exam_date.user = total_marks.user
```

If this isn't what you want could you explain it not in code. Eg, do you have a students table?

EDIT - For a list of the users (who have done an exam) I think the following might do it:-

```
SELECT exam_date.user, 
    English.percentage, 
    Biology.percentage, 
    Maths.percentage, 
    Science.percentage, 
    SocialStudies.percentage, 
    English.grade, 
    Biology.grade, 
    Maths.grade, 
    Science.grade, 
    SocialStudies.grade, 
    exam_date.ExamDate, 
    total_marks.TotalMarks
FROM (SELECT user, MAX(exam_date) AS ExamDate FROM exams_db GROUP BY user) as exam_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT user, percentage, grade FROM exams_db where subjecttype = 'English' GROUP BY user) as English ON exam_date.user = English.user
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT user, percentage, grade FROM exams_db where subjecttype = 'Biology' GROUP BY user) as Biology ON exam_date.user = Biology.user
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT user, percentage, grade FROM exams_db where subjecttype = 'Maths' GROUP BY user) as Maths ON exam_date.user = Maths.user
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT user, percentage, grade FROM exams_db where subjecttype = 'Science' GROUP BY user) as Science ON exam_date.user = Science.user
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT user, percentage, grade FROM exams_db where subjecttype = 'SocialStudies' GROUP BY user) as SocialStudies ON exam_date.user = SocialStudies.user
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT user, MAX(total_marks) AS TotalMarks FROM exams_db GROUP BY user) as total_marks ON exam_date.user = total_marks.user
```

Note I am a bit dubious about the total_marks field (your original query was just getting the highest total marks).

Possibly more efficient (but completely untested) would be:-

```
SELECT users.user, 
    exam_dates.ExamDate, 
    total_marks.TotalMarks, 
    MAX(IF(Sub1.subjecttype='English', exams_db.percentage, 0)) AS EnglishPercentage,
    MAX(IF(Sub1.subjecttype='English', exams_db.grade, 0)) AS EnglishGrade,
    MAX(IF(Sub1.subjecttype='Biology', exams_db.percentage, 0)) AS BiologyPercentage,
    MAX(IF(Sub1.subjecttype='Biology', exams_db.grade, 0)) AS BiologyGrade,
    MAX(IF(Sub1.subjecttype='Maths', exams_db.percentage, 0)) AS MathsPercentage,
    MAX(IF(Sub1.subjecttype='Maths', exams_db.grade, 0)) AS MathsGrade,
    MAX(IF(Sub1.subjecttype='Science', exams_db.percentage, 0)) AS SciencePercentage,
    MAX(IF(Sub1.subjecttype='Science', exams_db.grade, 0)) AS ScienceGrade,
    MAX(IF(Sub1.subjecttype='SocialStudies', exams_db.percentage, 0)) AS SocialStudiesPercentage,
    MAX(IF(Sub1.subjecttype='SocialStudies', exams_db.grade, 0)) AS SocialStudiesGrade
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT user, subjecttype, MAX(exam_date) AS LatestSubjectExam 
    FROM exams_db 
    WHERE subjecttype IN ('English', 'Biology', 'Maths', 'Science', 'SocialStudies') 
    GROUP BY user, subjecttype
) Sub1 ON users.user = Sub1.user
LEFT OUTER JOIN exams_db ON Sub1.user = exams_db.user AND Sub1.subjecttype = exams_db.subjecttype AND Sub1.LatestSubjectExam = exams_db.exam_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT user, MAX(total_marks) AS TotalMarks FROM exams_db GROUP BY user) total_marks ON users.user = total_marks.user
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT user, MAX(exam_date) AS ExamDate FROM exams_db GROUP BY user) exam_dates ON users.user = exam_dates.user
GROUP BY users.user, exam_dates.ExamDate, total_marks.TotalMarks
```

EDIT again

To try and cope with duplicate users / exams in the 2nd style query

```
SELECT exam_date.user, 
    English.percentage, 
    Biology.percentage, 
    Maths.percentage, 
    Science.percentage, 
    SocialStudies.percentage, 
    English.grade, 
    Biology.grade, 
    Maths.grade, 
    Science.grade, 
    SocialStudies.grade, 
    exam_date.ExamDate, 
    total_marks.TotalMarks
FROM (SELECT user, MAX(exam_date) AS ExamDate FROM exams_db GROUP BY user) as exam_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT user, subjecttype, MAX(exam_date) AS LatestSubjectExam 
    FROM exams_db 
    WHERE subjecttype IN ('English', 'Biology', 'Maths', 'Science', 'SocialStudies') 
    GROUP BY user, subjecttype
) Sub1 ON exam_date.user = Sub1.user
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT user, exam_date, percentage, grade FROM exams_db where subjecttype = 'English' GROUP BY user, exam_date) as English ON exam_date.user = English.user AND Sub1.subjecttype = 'English' AND Sub1.LatestSubjectExam = English.exam_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT user, exam_date, percentage, grade FROM exams_db where subjecttype = 'Biology' GROUP BY user, exam_date) as Biology ON exam_date.user = Biology.user AND Sub1.subjecttype = 'Biology' AND Sub1.LatestSubjectExam = Biology.exam_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT user, exam_date, percentage, grade FROM exams_db where subjecttype = 'Maths' GROUP BY user, exam_date) as Maths ON exam_date.user = Maths.user AND Sub1.subjecttype = 'Maths' AND Sub1.LatestSubjectExam = Maths.exam_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT user, exam_date, percentage, grade FROM exams_db where subjecttype = 'Science' GROUP BY user, exam_date) as Science ON exam_date.user = Science.user AND Sub1.subjecttype = 'Science' AND Sub1.LatestSubjectExam = Science.exam_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT user, exam_date, percentage, grade FROM exams_db where subjecttype = 'SocialStudies' GROUP BY user, exam_date) as SocialStudies ON exam_date.user = SocialStudies.user AND Sub1.subjecttype = 'SocialStudies' AND Sub1.LatestSubjectExam = SocialStudies.exam_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT user, MAX(total_marks) AS TotalMarks FROM exams_db GROUP BY user) as total_marks ON exam_date.user = total_marks.user
```

Comment: Am trying to output the details of the users like their names and what they have scored in each subject and the total marks they got.

Comment: In which case I suspect a UNION is not what you want (that will land up putting grades and percentages on different lines)

Comment: Yes thats one of the problems actually, and the other problem is that it works when i have only one record in the database for each subject. But when i have for example two 'Biologies', the query fails. 
You can relate to this Fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0640d/1

Comment: The final example I give should cope with multiple exams attempts at an exam for one person. Will try and get the 2nd query to cope in the same way

Comment: That second query gives an empty query result.

Comment: Could you do this in SQLFiddle please because all of the above queries return an empty query result.

Comment: It should work, and I can see nothing wrong with it beyond not being designed to cope with multiple exams in a single subject for a user (the 4th query should cope with that - just fixing a minor bug with that) and it does work when I give it a quick test. Afraid without more test data and database layouts I can't test it further (the couple of lines you give do not have the exam_date or total_marks columns).

Comment: Can't use the SQL fiddle setup straight off as the table you have set up is missing (at least) 3 columns. User, exam_date and total_marks columns. I have added those columns in sqlfiddle and it works fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29988/discussion-between-mutie-mule-and-kickstart)

Comment: Thanks, atleast this is helpful now. In my php echo statement what should i output?

Comment: Use the alias names from the select (eg 'EnglishPercentage' ). Echo them out in the order you require.

Comment: But something funny, it displays each percentage in a new line.

Comment: Err, the version I had working in SQL fiddle didn't. It had one row per user. If your script is displaying users over multiple lines it is a script / php issue

Comment: Struggled with it but yet it is having the same issue. Don't know if the grouping by could be the problem.

Comment: Can you post the script with the SQL in it? The GROUP BY bits are in the subselects and none should be needed in the main bit of the select.

Comment: I hacked it, I guess am a sql geek also. Thats alot @Kickstart for your help. You really saved me a lot. Thanks indeed. I just did away with some unnecessary joins.